# Design leading to break contravariance. How to avoid it?

Tags: object-oriented, php, liskov-substitution

I have a `Converter` which use a `Resolver` to determine which `Factory` to use when converting a `Resource` to a `Entity`. To do so, I need to be sure that the `Factory` has a `createFromResource` method.

The problem: I am not able to create an interface handling the Factories because of the contravariance of arguments. The `FactoryInterface` cannot set the argument of `createFromResource` method because it will change in every `Factory` implementation and doesn't have a common parent.

**How can I design those classes without breaking Liskov Substitution Principle? What I am doing wrong? Is that a bad design?**

Here are my classes:

```php
interface EntityInterface {}
```

```php
class UserEntity implements EntityInterface {}
```

```php
interface ResourceInterface {}
```

```php
class UserResource implements ResourceInterface {}
```

```php
class Converter
{
    private FactoryResolver $factoryResolver;

    public function convert(ResourceInterface $resource): EntityInterface
    {
        $factory = $this->factoryResolver->resolveFromResource($resource);

        // Need to ensure that $factory has createFromResource() method
        return $factory->createFromResource($resource);
    }
}
```

```php
class FactoryResolver
{
    public function resolveFromResource(ResourceInterface $resource): FactoryInterface;
}
```

```php
interface FactoryInterface
{
    // Cannot be implemented because of contravariance
    public function createFromResource(ResourceInterface $resource): EntityInterface;
}
```

```php
class UserFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    // This signature break contravariance
    public function createFromResource(UserResource $user): UserEntity;
}
```

PHP version: 7.4

**Thanks a lot !**

Comment: Why not just remove the Type Hints in the method signatures in the interface? PHP is still a dynamically-typed language.

Comment: @greg And also remove the type hint from `UserFactory::createFromResource()`? I need to be sure that its argument is a `ResourceInterface`. I could check it in the method body with `$user instanceof UserResource` and throw an exception if not but it also seems to break the Liskov Substitution Principle.

Comment: Already answered in https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/389503/ as far as the OOP Design issues are concerned. PHP may have some additional considerations (such as what Greg pointed out, PHP being a dynamically typed language), but the deeper issues of this use case with LSP is already fully debated in that earlier question.

Comment: The key observation is that the method `createFromResource` is a subtle example of overloading: between the classes (`UserResource` and `UserEntity`) there is one method `createFromResource`; between the classes (`AdminResource` and `AdminEntity`) there is a **different** method also named `createFromResource`. There is nothing interchangeable between those methods; they merely share the same name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your error highlights an important point: **Is there even a situation where you could treat `UserFactory` as if it was a `FactoryInterface`?**

Since `UserFactory.createFromResource` *requires* a `UserResource`, it's *less permissive* than `FactoryInterface.createFromResource`. This means that casting `UserResource` to `FactoryInterface` is unsafe no matter how you look at it.

Covariance and contravariance only tell you what's *guaranteed* to be safe with respect to automatic type conversions. When implementing an inherited function, argument types can never be more restrictive than what the parent allows; otherwise, it would be unsafe to actually use it as an instance of the parent.

In summary, it appears that `FactoryInterface` doesn't express a common property of its children in this case, since you can't discard knowledge of the underlying implementation.